# Chi-squared feature selection using Fselector in R

Tags: r, feature-extraction, chi-squared, fselector

I am a beginner in R and I have a `data frame` that has binary values in it. In my data frame, the first 6000 columns are the attributes I am going to select features from, and the last 10 columns (again binary) are the classes I need to train my data with.
I have learned that I can use the `Fselector` package to calculate the chi-squared value for each attribute, then rank-order them and select my features. I've found this example from `Fselector` package:

```
# Use HouseVotes84 data from  mlbench package
library(mlbench)# For data
library(FSelector)#For method
data(HouseVotes84)


#Calculate the chi square statistics 
weights<- chi.squared(Class~., HouseVotes84)


# Print the results 
print(weights)


# Select top five variables
subset<- cutoff.k(weights, 5)


# Print the final formula that can be used in classification
f<- as.simple.formula(subset, "Class")
print(f)
```

But when I write the same code for my data, R doesn't find the object `Class` after command `weights<- chi.squared(Class~., HouseVotes84)`. The Fselector package notes that a formula should be there, but I don't know what kind of formula. Should I write the mathematical formula of chisquare test there? Then what's the point of the package vs. using a For loop for calculating the X^2 statistic?

I am not going to use other packages like `quanteda` because I actually want to avoid typing in the whole formula of chi-square for feature selection. Do you have any suggestions for how to fix that line of code based on the structure of my data?

**UPDATE**: This is the first three rows of my data with 10 out of 6000 columns of terms. The last 10 columns are my classes.

```
   structure(list(rigid = c(0, 0, 0), sobaaox = c(0, 0, 0), intermittententsharpleft = c(0, 
0, 0), pnuemondayia = c(0, 0, 0), medport = c(0, 0, 0), assharp = c(0, 
0, 0), ambult = c(0, 0, 0), cmpliant = c(0, 0, 0), anlk = c(0, 
0, 0), scoliosi = c(0, 0, 0), espec = c(0, 0, 0), `290` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), `320` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `390` = c(1L, 0L, 0L), `460` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), `520` = c(0L, 1L, 0L), `580` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `710` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), `780` = c(0L, 0L, 1L), `800` = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `100001` = c(0L, 
0L, 0L)), .Names = c("rigid", "sobaaox", "intermittententsharpleft", 
"pnuemondayia", "medport", "assharp", "ambult", "cmpliant", "anlk", 
"scoliosi", "espec", "290", "320", "390", "460", "520", "580", 
"710", "780", "800", "100001"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What are your data ? Do you have a column `Class` ?

Comment: I don't have a column Class but I tried replacing "Class" with the those columns of my data that are my classes, like weights<- chi.squared(data1[,5091:6000]., data1[,1:5090]) and I got another error: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object '290' not found

Comment: Please show your data: `dput(mydata)` or `dput(head(mydata))`, and show the code you use on your data.

Comment: I added it as an update in my question. Does it work?

Comment: Have you attached the dataset? `attach(mydata)` where `mydata` is the name of the data frame.

Comment: I attached it as an "update" in my question above.